# Simulating DNA sequences in R with a given value of $\theta = 4N_{e}\mu$

Tags: population-genetics

This might not be the most appropriate site to be asking such a question, but perhaps someone has a solution.

**My question is**: is there an R package or function for simulation of DNA sequences of a given basepair length generated according to a prespecified value of the population mutation rate $\theta = 4N_{e}\mu$, where $N_{e}$ is the effective population size and $\mu$ is the per-generation mutation rate

I have real sequence data from GenBank, but I would also like to simulate some random DNA sequences according to a coalescent process.

Essentially the function would output the generated aligned DNA sequences as a FASTA file.

I have been rather unsuccessful in tracking down a suitable package, as most only output generated phylogenies.

Comment: @Remi.b Thanks. I'll do some sleuthing. If I don't come across anything, I will code it myself, or use SimBit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of tools but I don't know any that comes with an R library. They are usually all called from the command line. I don't either of any that produce FASTA file. [SimBit](https://github.com/RemiMattheyDoret/SimBit) (my own software) can produce `vcf` files which can easily be converted into FASTA with PGDspider.

However, if your simulations are so easy, you might not need these individual-based softwares. Just write the code yourself. It might only be take a few tens of lines. Here is a simple example

```
freq = 0.1 # initial frequency
N = 1000   # Constant population size
mu = 1e-7  # mutation rate

for (generation in 1:nbGenerations)
{
   # Drift
   freq = rbinom(1,N,freq) / N

   # Mutations
   oneWayMutations   = rbinom(1,N*freq,mu) / N
   otherWayMutations = rbinom(1,N*(1-freq),mu) / N
   freq = freq - oneWayMutations + otherWayMutations
}
```

If you need something more complex (such as several loci), then you should probably use one of the existing individual-based software. See the post [Sequence evolution simulation tool](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35108/sequence-evolution-simulation-tool)

Comment: What is the 'freq' variable in your example?

Comment: 'freq' is the frequency of a one allele at a single bi-allelic locus. If you want several linked loci, then you'll have to use some individual based software, such as SimBit, Nemo or SFS_code for examples. See edit in the post.

Comment: Thanks! I just came across @EliKorvigo 's post, as it was recently commented on.