# Selection coefficient of gorillas

Tags: population-genetics, selection

I've been reading about selective sweeps. And I found a case study that talks about drosophila and how their selection coefficient is between 0.0001 and 0.005.
I want to know what it'll be like for gorillas? That is what would be the selection coefficient range for them and why? Also, I was told that N*s of gorillas is between 100 and 10000 where N is the current population size and s is the selection coefficient.
Help would be really appreciated. I do not have a biological background therefore, it's taking some time to wrap my head around these things.

Comment: `I found a case study` Whether it seems to matter or not, please always link to your source.

Comment: A selection coefficient is not so much specific about a species as much as it is specific to a given mutation. What mutation are you talking about in gorillas?

Comment: Do you mean mutation rate? Per site mutation rate is 1.5e-08

Comment: No, I did not talk about mutation rate. A specific mutation has a selection coefficient. A species does not. It makes no sense to ask "What is the selection coefficient in gorillas?", it only makes sense to ask "What is the selection coefficient of the p.P252R mutation in gorillas?"

Comment: It's not a specific mutation. I want to simulate sweeps in the genome. I have all the parameters I need but I am struggling with the selection coefficient. I've edited the question and have added the parameters so you can see.

Comment: There are no correct answer then. If you simulate a selection coefficient of 0.3, then you will likely simulate something that is very rare. If you simulation a selection coefficient of 0.0001, then you won't even really have a selective sweep. Just pick a number in between. But there are no right or wrong.

Comment: ok. So what is usually the range for a strong selection? It'll be close to 1?

Comment: I would personally consider anything above 0.01 as being strong selection. You will likely never find a new beneficial mutation with a selection much higher than 0.1. On a side note, you might be interested in the Distribution of Fitness Effects of new mutations (DFE; although in general such distributions are only estimated for deleterious mutations as they are much more common).

Comment: On another side note, you might be interested in the post [Sequence evolution simulation tool](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35108/sequence-evolution-simulation-tool)